# c++ coroutines final_suspend for promise_type

Tags: c++, c++20

below is a snippet testing empty coroutine playing with promise_type

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>

#define DEBUG std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl

struct TaskSuspendAll {
      // must be of this name
    struct promise_type {
          TaskSuspendAll get_return_object() noexcept {
              return TaskSuspendAll{
                std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)
              };
          }
        std::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { 
            DEBUG;
            return {}; 
        }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept {
              DEBUG;
              return {};
          }
          void unhandled_exception() {}
          void return_void() {
              DEBUG;
          }
      };

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> ch;
  };

TaskSuspendAll TestSuspendAll() {
    DEBUG;
    co_return;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    auto t = TestSuspendAll();
    t.ch.resume();
    //t.ch.resume()
    //t.ch.destroy();

    return 0;
}
```

running this I get

```
std::__n4861::suspend_always TaskSuspendAll::promise_type::initial_suspend()
TaskSuspendAll TestSuspendAll()
void TaskSuspendAll::promise_type::return_void()
std::__n4861::suspend_always TaskSuspendAll::promise_type::final_suspend()
```

My understanding is that `co_await` is applied to `initial_suspend` and `final_suspend`. When I call `TestSuspendAll` in the `main` function it will eventually call `co_await promise.initial_suspend()` and return to the caller given i have `std::suspend_always` awaitable. Then i resume the coroutine and the body gets executed. At some point, we will have `co_await promise.final_suspend()` and again return to the caller.

question: I would expect that i have to do a second call to resume coroutine so that `co_await promise.final_suspend()` succeeded and coroutine completed. However that causes seg fault. I know that it's undefined behavior calling resume on completed coroutine, however it's not completed 100% as far as I understand. My expectation was that `final_suspend` behaves the same as `initial_suspend`... what is the logic here? is that we have to use destroy after call to `final_suspend`?

thanks a lot for clarification!

VK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being suspended at its final suspend point is the definition of a coroutine being done. Literally; [that's what `coroutine_handle::done` returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle/done). Attempting to [resume such a coroutine is UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle/resume).

So your expectation is not correct.